# How do I get the result of an http request in Swift 5 (iOS app) using Alamofire?

Tags: ios, json, swift, alamofire

I'm trying to get the resilt of an http request (a JSON file) from the following code:

```
public func performRequest(parameters: [String, String]) -> Any{
    var headers = HTTPHeaders(parameters)
    headers.add(name: "Content-Type", value: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8")
    
    var any : Any?
    
    AF.request(urlEndPointApp, method: .post, parameters: parameters, encoding: URLEncoding.httpBody,  headers: headers).validate().responseJSON{ response in
        switch response.result {
        case .success(let JSON): // stores the json file in JSON variable
            // the JSON file is printed correctly
            print("Validation Successful with response JSON \(JSON)")
            // this variable is seen as nil outside this function (even in return)
            any = JSON
        case .failure(let error):
        print("Request failed with error \(error)")
        }
    }
    
    return any
}
```

The problem is that, when I print the JSON file from the `print("Validation Successful with response JSON \(JSON)")` function, it gets printed correclty.
I even tried to print the variable any inside of the block using `print("Validation Successful with response JSON \(any)")` and it works, but when it gets returned, its value is `nil`.

Comment: You are missing the asynchronous concept. Use a closure to manage it, not a return value.

Comment: Consider not using Alamofire and learn how to use closures in plain Swift. It's especially easy when using the new Combine framework.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using an asynchronous method, so it means you get the result *after* some time.

You should change your method to

```
public func performRequest(parameters: [String, String], completion: @escaping (Result<Any, Error>) -> Void) {
    var headers = HTTPHeaders(parameters)
    headers.add(name: "Content-Type", value: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8")
    
    AF.request(urlEndPointApp, method: .post, parameters: parameters, encoding: URLEncoding.httpBody,  headers: headers).validate().responseJSON{ response in
        switch response.result {
        case .success(let JSON): // stores the json file in JSON variable
            // the JSON file is printed correctly
            print("Validation Successful with response JSON \(JSON)")
            // this variable is seen as nil outside this function (even in return)
            completion(.success(JSON))
        case .failure(let error):
            print("Request failed with error \(error)")
            completion(.failure(error))
        }
    }
}
```